# Vsftpd User Premissions

Tags: ubuntu, users, ftp, permissions

I've an Ubuntu Server. I installed vsftpd. I want that specific user will have full premissions to /var/www/someDirectory and her child directories/files. So I created a user with this commands:

```
useradd -b /var/www/someDirectory -d /var/www/someDirectory user1
passwd user1
chown user1 /var/www/someDirectory
```

It's working, and when this user login to the ftp, he's automatically in the path /var/www/someDirectory. The problem is, he can remove the someDirectory from the path, and see /var/www... he can write any path and he have full premssions to it...

I want that he will only can see/write/any premssion the /var/www/someDirectory and her child directories, and no other directory in the system.

How can I do it?

Thank you so much and sorry for my English - I hope you understood me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're searching for is chroot'ing. This limits a user to his home directory.

- [Vsftpd chroot users](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/vsftp-chroot-users-limit-to-only-their-home-directory.html)
- [Vsftpd conf](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html)

Best wishes,
Fabian